# SQL filter search according to multiple column values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I am dealing with one table(3+ million rows,SQL Server) 
I need to filter results according to the two columns below:

```
<code>
...FromID| ToID  |Column5|....
...1001    2001
...1002    2020 
...1003    5000    
...1001    3000 
...2001    1001 
</code>
```

Now User1 can access records with FromID or ToId 1001.
    
    `FromID|ToID
    1001|2001
    1001|3000
    2001|1001`

User2 can access records with FromID or ToID 1002,1003,3000
    
    `FromID|ToID
    1002|2020
    1003|5000
    1001|3000`

What is the most efficient way to do this ?
Do i need to create a view for each user ?(this is working on enterprise,user count will be
max 100 )
Thanks.

PS. My very first question. O.o

Comment: How do you know which user can access which records? Is by individual user or by which group they belong? Is the user rights stored anywhere?

Comment: Yes they are stored. In UserRights table.
User1|1001
User2|1002
User2|1003
User2|3000

Comment: Can you give the schema of the 'code' table? The answer will be a join between the tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your access criteria seem to be fairly arbitrary. User1 gets `1001`, user2 gets `1002`, `1003`, and `3000`, and I assume users 3 through 99 have arbitrary access as well. In that case, I recommend that you create a table, call it `useraccess` for this example:

```
user |accessID
---------------
user1|1001
user2|1002
user2|1003
user2|3000
...  |...
```

Now when you want to know what rows a user has, you can do this:

```
SELECT t.FromID, t.ToID, [[other columns you care about]]
FROM yourtable t
JOIN useraccess a ON t.FromID = a.accessID OR t.ToID = a.accessID
WHERE a.user = 'user2'
```

You can either run that query dynamically or you can create a view based on it. The usual tradeoffs between views and direct queries will apply as usual.

**Edit:** I just saw your note that you already have a `UserRights` table, so you already have step 1 completed.

Comment: Sorry i am not clear. The solution above is the one i am using. But 
i am having some performance issues. So If i created a different view
for each user would that be better or worse ? I am not sure about that

Comment: No, you shouldn't have to create a view for each user. If you're having performance issues with that query, I would say that you need to check your indexes. 3 million rows isn't really that much data as long as your join columns are indexed.

Comment: Per-user views would only save the lookup on the 'code' table. It would not help performance and just create a maintenance headache. If this query is too slow, you probably need to add two indexes, one on FromId and one on ToId.

Comment: Ah i see. I will recheck my indexes.